# Can't get json data from jQuery ajax call

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json

I'm trying to get data from `data.php` via jQuery ajax call.

My code looks like this:

```
var jsonData;

$.ajax({
        url: 'data.php',
        success: function(response) {
            jsonData = response;
        }
});
```

My `data.php` file is returning json formatted data but some text is in Unicode format.
I set charset on `data.php` and on my javascript file, but still cant access responced data objects.

Any ideas?

Comment: Are you trying to access your `jsonData` variable immediately after calling `$.ajax()`? It would be `undefined` at that point because your ajax call is asynchronous. Do your processing inside the `success` handler. (If that's not it, please click "edit" and add detail about what "can't access" actually means in this case. What actually ends up in your `response` variable?)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Try to put `dataType: 'json'` in you ajax call:

```
var jsonData;

$.ajax({
        url: 'data.php',
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(response) {
            jsonData = response;
        }
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Also you can use this mechanism:

```
$.getJSON( "data.php", function( response ) {
    jsonData = response;
});
```

It is more clean if you want get only JSON :)

Comment: hmmm.. didn't even know that function existed.. good to know :)

Answer (score 1):

You should be using `header()` function in your `PHP` to set the proper response header (content type and charset):

```
header('Content-type: application/json; charset=UTF-8');
```

You should also repeat this at the top of HTML pages:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-type" value="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
```

**See also:**

[PHP UTF-8 cheatsheet](http://blog.loftdigital.com/blog/php-utf-8-cheatsheet)

Answer (score 1):

PHP

```
try {
    $dbh = new PDO("mysql:host=$dbhost;dbname=$dbname", $dbuser, $dbpass);  
    $dbh->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    $dbh->query('SET NAMES utf8;');
    $stmt = $dbh->prepare($sql);  
    //$stmt->bindParam("id", $_GET[id]);
    $stmt->execute();

    $advice = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
    $dbh = null;
    echo '{"items":'. json_encode($advice) .'}'; 
} catch(PDOException $e) {
    echo '{"error":{"text":'. $e->getMessage() .'}}'; 
}
```

Ajax

```
 var temp;
    $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            url: serviceurl,
            data: "{'userName':'" + userName + "' , 'password': '" + password                                   
                   + "'}",
            dataType: "json",
            success: function(msg) {
                            temp = jQuery.parseJSON(msg.d);
                          },
            error: function(xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {}

        });
```

Answer (score 0):

data.php

```
header('Content-type: application/json');
```

and

```
$.ajax({
        url: 'data.php',
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(response) {
            jsonData = response;
        }
});
```