# Displaying more error details

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json, jsonp

I am trying to use json data from an external provider api's.  When I type their json url into the browser, it shows all the json data I need to see.  However, when I try to access it using jquery, I get errors, even though google chrome shows the correct json data in the dev tools section:

[image]

Because of this, I assume it means that the data is actually getting retrieved?  Anyway, this is the script I am using:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "https://some_url_here_from_different_domain.json",
    type: 'GET',
    dataType: 'jsonp',
    jsonp: 'callback',
    error: function(xhr, status, error) {
        alert(error); //<- returns Error: jQuery11020135121880332008_1387982597648 was not called
        alert(xhr.responseText); //<- returns undefined
    },
    success: function(data) { 
        alert("success");
    }
});
```

How do I get further error details so I can understand what's causing the error to appear?

Comment: Please check this link - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7202603/jquery-ajax-jsonp

Comment: That link is about POSTing data. This is about getting

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your JSONP code is fine and *should work*, but the endpoint you're calling in the example is returning JSON instead of JSONP regardless of your code.

Endpoint: https://localbitcoins.com/sell-bitcoins-online/national-bank-transfer/.json?callback=jQuery110202691209970507771_1387997968891&_=1387997968892

Difference: [What are the differences between JSON and JSONP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2887209/what-are-the-differences-between-json-and-jsonp)

Possible solutions:

1. Contact localbitcoins and ask them to enable JSONP for that URL
2. Setup a proxy server to pull in the data and return JSONP yourself - good starting point might be: https://npmjs.org/package/json-proxy

Comment: Why would they provide a public api which only returns json, and not jsonp?  What use is data especially when it's public if it can't be used cross domain?

Answer (score 0):

So far my understanding, you want to get json data using ajax call.

According to this link - [Can't get json data from jQuery ajax call](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19475991/cant-get-json-data-from-jquery-ajax-call)

Use dataType: 'json' instead of 'jsonp'

```
var jsonData;

$.ajax({
        url: "https://some_url_here_from_different_domain.json",
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(response) {
            jsonData = response;
        }
});
```

Comment: I think I need to specify jsonp because it's cross domain.  Please look at the second link in my question to see what happens with I don't specify jsonp.