# Jquery $.GET handling data

Tags: jquery

I am running a $.get call to get data from a php file:

```
 $.get("test.php", { home_type: home_info[0],  home_community: home_info[1] }, function(data) {
                        console.log(data);
 });
```

and it returns this data:

```
[{"id":"1", "title":"aaa"}, {"id":"2", "title":"bbb"}]
```

I tried to use a foreach method to use this data:

```
$.each(data, function (y, z) {
                                console.log(y);
                                console.log(z);
                        });
```

y returns a number starting at 1 and keeps counting up and z is each character in the data :( This is not what I was expecting. What do I have to get run a foreach and use each item at a time.

Comment: Your javascript is not evaluating your return data correctly as JSON data, and is instead treating it as a string. Try this instead: http://api.jquery.com/jquery.getjson/

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can't get json data from jQuery ajax call](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19475991/cant-get-json-data-from-jquery-ajax-call)

Comment: The y is the key of your array in the collection, and z is the object of that element.

Answer (score 4):

```
$.get("test.php", {

    home_type: home_info[0],
    home_community: home_info[1]

}, function (response) {

    var data = JSON.parse(response);
    $.each(data, function (index, value) {

        // Do something with each item...
        console.log(index);
        console.log(value);

    };

});
```

Comment: Yeah, alternatively use `.getJSON()` or `$.get(url, data, function(){...}, 'json')` to make jQuery parse the returned string  automatically.

Comment: @Spokey: Good call, I always forget about `.getJSON()`!

Answer (score 0):

You need to convert your json string to object, just use parseJSON(data) and it will convert your to JSON object.

Answer (score 0):

If you want access your data, try this:

```
var data = [{"id": "1", "title": "aaa"}, {"id": "2", "title": "bbb"}];
$.each(data, function(y, z) {
    console.log(z.id);
    console.log(z.title);
    //This is the same as
    console.log("Other way " + data[y].id);
    console.log("Other way " + data[y].title);
});
```

`y` is the array key of the current object in the array, while `z` is the object itself.